# SVN does not transfer files larger than ~512 MB (OOM Killer)

Tags: server, transfer, svn

I have moved a repository from one server to another. On the client, I have deleted the repository and I'm now trying to checkout from the new server again.

This works fine for small files. I was able to check out hundreds of small files with a total size of >4000 MB. But whenever it comes to a large file, I get the error message

> Error running context: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

At the moment I get this regularly, TortoiseSVN on the client says:

> 520,00 MBytes transferred in 2 minute(s) and 55 second(s)

It seems I'm affected by the OOM killer:

```
x:~$ sudo dmesg
[...]
[290354.745160] Out of memory: Kill process 19409 (apache2) score 843 or sacrifice child
[290354.745585] Killed process 19409 (apache2) total-vm:19200784kB, anon-rss:11311540kB, file-rss:692kB
```

I wonder a bit why Apache is killed. After it was killed, it seems there's 9 GB of RAM left:

```
x:~$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         12043       2103       9940         87         54        313
```

Using `top` I see the following, shortly before it gets killed:

[image: Screenshot of Apache getting killed soon]

I can hardly believe that it's normal for Apache to consume 17 GB of memory for a file of 692 MB (which is according the Repo browser the one that causes the issue).

What could I do to make the files transfer? I do not want to disable the OOM killer globally. I'd like to figure out why Apache needs so much RAM and what to do against that, e.g. via Apache config files, upgrading to a non-memory-leaked version or similar.

I have tried:

- [following this blog](https://monicalent.com/blog/2013/03/27/avoiding-the-oom-killer-by-limiting-the-number-of-apache2-processes/), but in my `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` there are no such entries.
- [Ubuntu formus](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2070853) mention the issue for 1 GB RAM. Upgrading to 2 GB helped. Unfortunately I cannot upgrade RAM. I cannot get more than the 12 GB I have. I looks sufficient to me. My old server had 2 GB only and worked fine as well.

Versions:

```
x:~$ sudo apache2ctl -V
Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
Server built:   Sep 20 2017 04:37:43

x:~$ svn --version
svn, version 1.8.10 (r1615264)
   compiled Aug 10 2017, 03:35:22 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

x:~$ uname -a
Linux v2201506722726049 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.43-2+deb8u5 (2017-09-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not figure it out. On 10th of January, all my kernels were deleted and I reinstalled the server from scratch. It now works normally. Transferring even 4000 MB files is easily possible. Memory of Apache only went up to ~400 MB.